# How to display description in corresponding to id in pop up window

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to print a row of data from MySQL using PHP. It include title, image, description.

I have already print title and image in index page and I need to print corresponding description in popup window.

My problem is arising when I trying to print image ,title, link to popup window repeatedly in index page. I couldn't print corresponding description in pop up window.

[This is my screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEMGS.jpg)

Comment: where is your screen?

Comment: where is the screen ?

Comment: How you pass the data/parameters in your popup window?

Comment: i didnt pass  any parameter. i dont knw how to do it